# Azure App Service Deploy fails with "Status Code: 404 Not Found" on Azure Government Cloud

Tags: azure-devops, azure-gov

We are trying to set up a release pipeline for an app service in Azure DevOps that is to run in an Azure Government Cloud resource.

We have created a service connection to the proper subscription, with the Environment set correctly. I can verify the connection in the service connection dialog and have verified the subscription id, tenant id, service principal client id and key.

The Azure App Service Deploy task takes the subscription, and enumerates the App service name without any issue.

However, when we run the release, we get the following error:

```
2019-03-06T18:54:28.4346907Z <snip> exists true
2019-03-06T18:54:29.9479375Z ##[error]Not Found
2019-03-06T18:54:29.9503993Z ##[error]Unable to retrieve App ID for Azure App Service:'my-app-service'. Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

I can't find any reference to this error online or in docs. I also don't know what the App ID it is referring to is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is in your regular build output? Any other context you can provide? is the "my-app-service" something you all referred to somewhere? Or is this the thing you're not sure where it's coming from? Think we need more info.

Comment: This is in the release pipeline "Deploy Azure App Service" task output. It is Azure App Service Deploy v 2.1.14. I'm not sure what further context you need. It's a bog-standard deployment of an App Service to Azure, except that it's being deployed to a Azure Government Cloud resource instead of a standard one. This deployment works in 6 other pipelines.